# Custom Azure Devops Status Check Not Triggering on push for Azure Git Repos

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a custom PR status check to validate my PR follows a conventional commit like pattern. This is in Azure Devops Git, *not* Github. To do this, I created an Azure Function App and setup a status check in Azure Devops. Here is the configuration:
[image]
[image]

I enabled the PR status check for my branch. Here is the config for that:
[image]

The PR status check appears and actually works....when I invoke the call manually. I can use postman to invoke my function (with a PAT I generated for my account) and it will update the status on the PR. But if I commit to the branch, the step sits there on the validation step even though I have the checkbox checked to "Reset status when there are new changes".
[image]

This is what it looks like after I invoke the function manually through postman
[image]

I would expect the system (AZDO in this case) to invoke my function every time a new iteration was created (i.e. when a new commit is pushed to the branch). Can someone point out what I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up coming up with solution. I don't have privs to add a an authenticate an application to run the pipeline because of the way our org is setup. So I created a node script to accomplish what the function app is supposed to do.